How to rank and reassign values to subset of Python dataframe
Drawing a blank, please advise.
Have a dataframe, d:
    Position  Operation  Side   Price  Size
0          0          0     1  0.7288   -17
1          8          0     1  0.7297   -14
2          7          0     1  0.7296    -8
3          6          0     1  0.7295  -426
4          5          0     1  0.7294   -16
5          4          0     1  0.7293   -16
6          3          0     1  0.7292   -15
7          2          0     1  0.7291  -267
8          1          0     1  0.7290  -427
9          0          0     1  0.7289   -16
10         0          0     0  0.7299     6
11         1          0     0  0.7300    34
12         2          0     0  0.7301     7
13         3          0     0  0.7302     9
14         4          0     0  0.7303    16
15         5          0     0  0.7304    15
16         6          0     0  0.7305   429
17         7          0     0  0.7306    16
18         8          0     0  0.7307   265
19         9          0     0  0.7308    18

That I'd like to filter based on column value, such as:
d.loc[(d.Side==1)]

   Position  Operation  Side   Price  Size
0         0          0     1  0.7288   -17
1         8          0     1  0.7297   -14
2         7          0     1  0.7296    -8
3         6          0     1  0.7295  -426
4         5          0     1  0.7294   -16
5         4          0     1  0.7293   -16
6         3          0     1  0.7292   -15
7         2          0     1  0.7291  -267
8         1          0     1  0.7290  -427
9         0          0     1  0.7289   -16

I'd then like to rank based on Price, and assign the rank to a column in the subset dataframe, specifically Position.
For instance, filtering based on Side = 1, and then ranking based on Price, I'd like my updated dataframe, d, to look like this.
    Position  Operation  Side   Price  Size
0          0          0     1  0.7288   -17
1          9          0     1  0.7297   -14
2          8          0     1  0.7296    -8
3          7          0     1  0.7295  -426
4          6          0     1  0.7294   -16
5          5          0     1  0.7293   -16
6          4          0     1  0.7292   -15
7          3          0     1  0.7291  -267
8          2          0     1  0.7290  -427
9          1          0     1  0.7289   -16
10         0          0     0  0.7299     6
11         1          0     0  0.7300    34
12         2          0     0  0.7301     7
13         3          0     0  0.7302     9
14         4          0     0  0.7303    16
15         5          0     0  0.7304    15
16         6          0     0  0.7305   429
17         7          0     0  0.7306    16
18         8          0     0  0.7307   265
19         9          0     0  0.7308    18

Where '0' is the lowest value and '9' is the largest--df.rank returns a one-indexed float rank, but it's easy enough to get from there to the int 0-9 values I need.

df['Position'] = df.groupby('Side')['Price'].rank().astype('int').sub(1)

@PandaKim, yup, that'll work...got confused earlier checking the documentation and seeing the 'method' parameter.  thanks, bud
